# What do I need to use the Websphere Portal scripting interface?

Tags: scripting, administration, websphere-portal

### My Problem

I had to change some config settings in Websphere Portal several times over the last few weeks. It gets boring now and I want to replace myself with a little script.

I need access to the section **Manage pages** and in/activate some content nodes.

- log in
- navigate to **Manage pages**
- search for a unique name
- click the **Activate**/**Inactivate** link
- confirm the dialog
- log out

### I want to script this task

I created a Selenium script for this, but this still involves opening Firefox, loading the Selenium script into the Selenium IDE, provide the password (because I feel dirty when I save it into the script) and run it on all 3 clusters.

I read about Portal scripting and I want to try that. But unfortunatly I only have Websphere Application server installed on my machine and therefore only **wsadmin.bat/sh** is available for me.

### What do I need to run Websphere Portal scripts?

There is a script **wpscript.bat/sh** that I need to use. Do I have to install *Websphere Portal* on my local machine? Is there a minimal setup that I can use? Can I just copy some JARs and go on?

Answer (score 1):

XMLAccess is what you are looking for. XMLAccess is a command line tool which comes with the Portal Server. It allows you to connect to a local or remote portal server and execute tasks like deploy portlets, add / remove pages, set parameters, activate / inactivate pages, etc.

XMLAccess uses XML based files to administrate tasks.

**Where is it?**

Look in the 'PORTAL_INSTALL_DIR/Portal Server/bin directory'

**How to start XMLAccess?**

```
./xmlaccess.sh -in your_xmlaccess_file.xml -url http://localhost:10040/wps/config -out message_log.txt ...
```

Please refer the [IBM Portal InfoCenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/index.jsp) for detailed description.

**How does a XMLAccess XML file looks like?**

There are examples in your portal installation. Look at `PORTAL_INSTALL_DIR/Portal Server/doc/xml-samples`.